# Binary tree code works on Linux but not on Windows 10

Tags: c, linux, windows, data-structures, binary-tree

The code I have works on Linux with no memory errors and the tree builds correctly when run on Linux, but when I run it on Windows with it gets stuck and terminates.

```
struct node {
    char letter;
    char *string;
    int last_node;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

static struct node nodes[] =
{
    {'\0', ""},
    {'E', "."},
    {'T', "-"},
    {'I', ".."},
    {'A', ".-"},
    {'N', "-."},
    {'M', "--"},
    {'S', "..."},
    {'U', "..-"},
    {'R', ".-."},
    {'W', ".--"},
    {'D', "-.."},
    {'K', "-.-"},
    {'G', "--."},
    {'O', "---"},
    {'H', "...."},
    {'V', "...-"},
    {'F', "..-."},
    {'\0', "..--"},
    {'L', ".-.."},
    {'\0', ".-..-"},
    {'P', ".--."},
    {'J', ".---"},
    {'B', "-..."},
    {'X', "-..-"},
    {'C', "-.-."},
    {'Y', "-.--"},
    {'Z', "--.."},
    {'Q', "--.-"},
    {'\0', "---."},
    {'\0', "----"},
    {'5', "....."},
    {'4', "....-"},
    {'\0', "...-."},
    {'3', "...--"},
    {'\0', "..-.."},
    {'\0', "..-.-"},
    {'\0', "..--."},
    {'2', "..---"},
    {'\0', ".-..."},
    {'\0', ".-..-"},
    {'\0', ".-.-."},
    {'\0', ".-.--"},
    {'\0', ".--.."},
    {'\0', ".--.-"},
    {'\0', ".---."},
    {'1', ".----"},
    {'6', "-...."},
    {'\0', "-...-"},
    {'/', "-..-."},
    {'\0', "-..--"},
    {'\0', "-.-.."},
    {'\0', "-.-.-"},
    {'\0', "-.--."},
    {'\0', "-.---"},
    {'7', "--..."},
    {'\0', "--..-"},
    {'\0', "--.-."},
    {'\0', "--.--"},
    {'8', "---.."},
    {'\0', "---.-"},
    {'9', "----."},
    {'0', "-----"},
    {.last_node = 1}
};

struct node *
tree_insert(struct node *root, struct node *selnode_addr, char *string)
{
    if (string[0] == '.')
    {
        if (string[1] == 0)
        {
            return root -> left = selnode_addr;
        }
        return tree_insert(root -> left, selnode_addr, string + 1);
    }

    if (string[1] == 0)
    {
        return root -> right = selnode_addr;
    }
    return tree_insert(root -> right, selnode_addr, string + 1);
}

int
main(void)
{
    // constructs the binary tree.
    for (struct node *nodeptr = nodes + 1; !nodeptr -> last_node; nodeptr++)
    {
        tree_insert(nodes, nodeptr, nodeptr -> string);
    }

    puts("test");
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux it runs and prints 'test' and passes valgrind with no memory errors and I've verified in GDB that the tree builds correctly, but on Windows it hangs for a short time and then seemingly crashes. I have no idea why.

**Updates**

- compiler is gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
- I tried `-std=c99 -pedantic` which didn't work either.
- Braden Best suggested removing the null nodes on the bottom of the tree and then it worked. New working tree provided below.

New array:

```
static struct node nodes[] =
{
    {'\0', ""},
    {'E', "."},
    {'T', "-"},
    {'I', ".."},
    {'A', ".-"},
    {'N', "-."},
    {'M', "--"},
    {'S', "..."},
    {'U', "..-"},
    {'R', ".-."},
    {'W', ".--"},
    {'D', "-.."},
    {'K', "-.-"},
    {'G', "--."},
    {'O', "---"},
    {'H', "...."},
    {'V', "...-"},
    {'F', "..-."},
    {'\0', "..--"},
    {'L', ".-.."},
    {'P', ".--."},
    {'J', ".---"},
    {'B', "-..."},
    {'X', "-..-"},
    {'C', "-.-."},
    {'Y', "-.--"},
    {'Z', "--.."},
    {'Q', "--.-"},
    {'\0', "---."},
    {'\0', "----"},
    {'5', "....."},
    {'4', "....-"},
    {'3', "...--"},
    {'2', "..---"},
    {'1', ".----"},
    {'6', "-...."},
    {'/', "-..-."},
    {'7', "--..."},
    {'8', "---.."},
    {'9', "----."},
    {'0', "-----"},
    {.last_node = 1}
};
```

Comment: windows most likely isn't initializing the rest of the fields you don't mention in the array to NULL.

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `root -> left` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `root->left`.

Comment: You don't seem to capture the result returned by `tree_insert()` in the `main()` function, but you almost certainly should.  You should be able to print the tree – if only you showed a function to do so.

Comment: @bruceg Isn't it required to?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it wanted to claim conformance to the latest standard, you're right. The OP doesn't indicate what compiler and version is being used though. I guess some old version of. VS.

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux for me: after several recursions, `root` is `NULL` on line: `return root -> left = selnode_addr;`

Comment: It's interesting that there is no dynamic memory allocation in the code.  The pre-existing `nodes` array is used.  Because the array is defined outside any function, any elements not explicitly listed in the initializers are zeroed (null pointers).

Comment: @bruceg Are you sure? The array is static. I know windows can be fucky, but `static` objects especially are guaranteed to be zero'd out by default. Not to mention, elements left empty in a partial definition are guaranteed to be zero'd out. `static char array[32];` and `char array[32] = "p";`, for example, are guaranteed to be 32 zeros and p followed by 31 zeros, respectively

Comment: @BradenBest I'm just guessing. Last time I used VS to compile C code was 15 years ago, and you couldn't depend on it to initialize anything back then. It would be easy for the OP to check though.

Comment: When writing code, do not "assume" that the compiler will do anything.  I see plenty of ***bugs*** in your code as-written.

Comment: I would initialize the structs like this to start: `{'\0', "", 0, NULL, NULL},

Comment: Tested with gcc 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04, `-Wall -Wextra -g -Wno-missing-field-initializers`, and found one error in valgrind in tree_insert. It appears to find an address at 0x18 and attempt to dereference it, i.e. undefined behavior. Interestingly, when I tested it the first time, I had removed all the nodes from the bottom of the tree, letting them be null, as I had deemed them unnecessary, and the code ran fine with no memory errors. I asked sinan to try removing those nodes and it worked on his end, too

Comment: I have no idea why the first version of the array causes an error while the one that leaves the pointers at the bottom null for unused codes doesn't. That's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a string to the tree, your code assumes that every prefix of that string has already been inserted. This mostly works because the strings are sorted by length.

However, the strings `.-.-.` and `.-.--` are inserted to the tree while their prefix `.-.-` is never inserted. This causes a recursive call to `tree_insert` with `root == NULL`. I'm surprised this doesn't crash for you on Linux, as it did for me.

In your fixed code you removed the `.-.-.` and `.-.--` strings so it works.

Comment: wow, good catch! I helped OP write some of the code and told him to transcribe every single permutation in depth-order, so I assumed he'd done so. There should've been a placeholder node there, rather than a null pointer. `root == NULL` would absolutely invoke UB with the way I wrote [`tree_insert`](https://pastebin.com/raw/0hfwsqBa).